# Parsing html into a list or a table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I extracted a `html` page using Selenium, and I want to put the data into a table / list that I can feed into pandas Dataframe.

**html extracted with Beautifulsoup 4**

```
    <tr class="result even">
     <td class="companyName" data-name="companyName">
      <a href="http://sgx.com/wps/portal/sgxweb/home/company_disclosure/stockfacts?page=1&amp;code=5TG" target="_parent">
       800 Super Holdings Limited
      </a>
     </td>
     <td class="tickerCode" data-name="tickerCode">
      5TG
     </td>
     <td class="industry" data-name="industry">
      Commercial Services and Supplies
     </td>
     <td class="marketCap" data-name="marketCap">
      84.9
     </td>
     <td class="percentChange hidden" data-name="percentChange">
      -
     </td>
     <td class="priceVs52WeekHigh hidden" data-name="priceVs52WeekHigh">
      (12.04)
     </td>
     <td class="priceVs52WeekLow hidden" data-name="priceVs52WeekLow">
      18.75
     </td>
     <td class="beta5Yr hidden" data-name="beta5Yr">
      0.371
     </td>
     <td class="volume hidden" data-name="volume">
      0.02 mm
     </td>
     <td class="avgTradedVolM3 hidden" data-name="avgTradedVolM3">
      0.1
     </td>
     <td class="avgVolumeM3 hidden" data-name="avgVolumeM3">
      0.13 mm
     </td>
     <td class="floatPercentage hidden" data-name="floatPercentage">
      84.11
     </td>
     <td class="priceVolHistYr hidden" data-name="priceVolHistYr">
      19.95
     </td>
     <td class="totalRevenue" data-name="totalRevenue">
      152
     </td>
     <td class="ebitdaMargin hidden" data-name="ebitdaMargin">
      15.15
     </td>
     <td class="netProfitMargin hidden" data-name="netProfitMargin">
      11.77
     </td>
     <td class="eps hidden" data-name="eps">
      0.1
     </td>
     <td class="totalDebtEquity hidden" data-name="totalDebtEquity">
      78.47
     </td>
     <td class="totalRev1YrAnnGrowth hidden" data-name="totalRev1YrAnnGrowth">
      19.4
     </td>
     <td class="totalRev3YrAnnGrowth hidden" data-name="totalRev3YrAnnGrowth">
      18.17
     </td>
     <td class="totalRev5YrAnnGrowth hidden" data-name="totalRev5YrAnnGrowth">
      15.83
     </td>
     <td class="basicEpsIncl hidden" data-name="basicEpsIncl">
      0.1
     </td>
     <td class="returnOnEquity hidden" data-name="returnOnEquity">
      34.77
     </td>
     <td class="peRatio" data-name="peRatio">
      4.745
     </td>
     <td class="dividendYield" data-name="dividendYield">
      4.21
     </td>
     <td class="priceToBookRatio hidden" data-name="priceToBookRatio">
      1.448
     </td>
     <td class="avgBrokerReq hidden" data-name="avgBrokerReq">
      -
     </td>
     <td class="gtiScore hidden" data-name="gtiScore">
      47
     </td>
     <td class="gtiRankChange hidden" data-name="gtiRankChange">
      (73)
     </td>
    </tr>
```

This html stretches for another 349 rows. How can I turn this into a table/list?

Would it be easier / faster to use lxml instead of bs4?

Comment: well, lxml will be slightly faster because beautifulsoup uses a parser built on top of lxml, but if you're just parsing one page the difference would be negligible.  as far as 'turning' the data into a table or a list, you should check out the beautifulsoup documentation for accessing the child of a parent's tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load it directly into the pandas dataframe with [`pandas.read_html()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html). It would use the best available/installed parser - install `lxml` if you want the speed.

Comment: I tried it and it gave me the error `Cannot read object of type 'ResultSet'`. What should I do?